# How to format a range if one of its cells contains some specific value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I wish to change the color of the target cells (B6 to H6), if any of the cell (B6 to H6) is containing either G1, G2, G3 OR G4(string search).

Say if F6 is G4 then the cells (B6 to H6) should turn green. I've attached the photo for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the actual string `G1` or the value in the cell G1?

Comment: ...and if it's about searching for the contents of `G1` through `G4`, then that does not match with the example image, I'd say.

Comment: I'm Interested in searching "G1" or "G2" till G4 in the cells B6 to H6. And if any of the cells B6 to H6 has "G1" or "G2" or "G3" or "G4", then the cells B6 to H6 should change to the color which I would specify in the conditional formatting.

Comment: Do you mean that if ANY of the cells have G1-4 then ALL of the cells turn green? That's a different story altogether.

Comment: Yes airstrike. That's the point. All the cells should turn green.

Comment: You can wither provide me a solution to this, or I'll put it the other way round. As the inputs in the cells B6 to H6 will be G1-4 so if all of the cells B6 to H6 are empty (null value) then the color of the targeted cells shouldn't change. And if any of the cells B6 to H6 has any value, then all the cells, B6 to H6 should turn green. 

This I want as a secondary solution. My original problem remains the same. As mentioned by you in the point above, @airstrike.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar =SUM(COUNTIF($B$6:$H$6,{"G1","G2","G3","G4"}))

Comment: "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for conditional formatting criteria."

That's the error I got, after I run the formula above.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar Use Matches instead of the {"G1,...,"G4"} sorry

Comment: For the record, I've edited my answer below to address your latest comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `B6:H6` then add a conditional formatting rule with the formula:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(B6,$G$1:$G$4,0),0)>0`

**EDIT**

If indeed you're searching for string as @Arjan mentioned, then I'd create a named range (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) with the value:

`={"G1","G2","G3","G4"}`

Let's name it `Matches` for lack of a better name.

[image]

Then I'd select B6:H6 and add the following conditional formatting rule:

`=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(Matches,B6)))>0`

Finally, if you want the rule to have *all* of the conditionally formatted cells highlighted if *any* of the cells contain "G1", "G2", "G3" or "G4", then the formula is:

`=SUM(COUNTIF($B$6:$H$6,Matches))>0`

Note that this will match entire cell contents only. If you want would like something like "foo G1 bar" to be a positive match, change the definition of Matches to be:

`={"*G1*","*G2*","*G3*","*G4*"}`

Comment: I'm quite sure the question is about searching for the text "G1", "G2" and so on, or otherwise the example screenshot is wrong.

Comment: @Arjan I thought of that after I had submitted the answer. I guess you're right, so I've edited the question to address that interpretation.

Comment: @airstrike, I tried your formula but I don't think it's solving my problem. I've added a comment to the question, you can have a look at it for a better understanding of the question. 

I think using just B6 in the formula =SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(Matches,B6))) is not helping to highlight all the cells from B6 to H6.

Comment: Thank You for the help @airstrike. Just on e more help. I'm now trying to drag it to all the rows below it till B38:H38. And when I dragged the cells it's behaving in an unexpected manner. 

Eg. After selecting B6:H6 and dragging it to B38:H38, only the inputs of "G1....4" in cells B6:H6 changes the colors of all the cells till H38. While inputting "G1....4" in any other cell eg. B8 doesn't change the color of that row. 
I wish the color changing for each row. Eg. Input "G3" in cell B18 turns B18 to H18 green.
Otherwise, for one row the suggestion is perfect.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar There are two ranges here: (A) where the conditional formatting is applied and (B) where to check for "G1...4" to trigger formatting. For (A), you click somewhere inside B6:H6 and go to Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules (`Alt` `H` `L` `R`) then edit the range to which the formtating is applied by editing the value in the "Applies To" column. For (B), you have to change what's being refered to in the COUNTIF formula.

Comment: And when you have a chance, please consider marking the answer as accepted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in you Conditional Formatting:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("G1",B6)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("G2",B6)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("G3",B6)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("G4",B6)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried using this. But the issue is i was successful in coloring just one cell and that's the cell in which I'm writing "G1" or "G2"... "G4". What I want to get done is that on typing "G1"......"G4" in any of the cells from B6:H6 should color all the cells B6:H6.

Comment: Like in the picture you would put the range to which you want the conditional formatting to apply in the Applies to box. The formula should only reference the upper left of that range.